# How to ignore body element style when there is a class at element inside

Tags: html, css

Look, i have the html below:

```
<body style="color:red;">
text inside 1
<p>
text inside p
...
</p>
<div class="divable1">
text inside div 1
</div>

</body>
```

and i want only "text inside 1" and "text inside p" to have color red BUT "text inside div 1" i want to ignore the style of the body element.

How is this possible with CSS?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, that is not possible. If you want the text content of `.divable1` to have a different color, then create a rule that specifies that different color.

Comment: ok so only if i set a color style to divable i can avoid the body's style,right? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to ignore rules in CSS, only to override them. Write a ruleset with:

- A selector that matches the div (such as `.divable1`)
- A rule that changes the `color` property so it has a value other than the default, which is `inherit`, such as `color: black`.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic CSS hierarchy, you can't ignore the rules, but you can easily overwrite them:

```
body {
    color: red;
}
.divable1 {
    color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vLtqjjpk/

Comment: Good one but i want to succed that without setting divable color style.Sorry.

Comment: Then you can use body :not(.divable1) or something in jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this question was asked a very long time ago, but it could possibly be done by unsetting one or all properties:

```css
body {
  color: red;
}

.divable1 {
  all: unset; /* resets everything */
  color: unset; /* resets specific property */
}
```